# Turn off keyboard backlight, Asus laptop (Ubuntu 15.10)

Tags: keyboard, 15.10, backlight

When I boot up my laptop ([Asus K501UX](https://www.asus.com/Notebooks/K501UX/)) keyboard backlight is turned on automatically. I want to turn it off by default, when Ubuntu is loaded, without using any hot keys.

sudo find /sys/class/leds/ output:

```
/sys/class/leds/
/sys/class/leds/asus::kbd_backlight
/sys/class/leds/phy0-led
/sys/class/leds/input3::scrolllock
/sys/class/leds/input3::capslock
/sys/class/leds/input3::numlock
/sys/class/leds/asus::wlan
```

Comment: Please open a shell and post the output of this command: `sudo find /sys/class/leds/`

Comment: @cmks I have edited my question, please take a look, thank you for your response

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a bash-script:

```
sudo gedit /usr/sbin/asuskbbloff
```

with this content:

```
#!/bin/bash

KBBL="/sys/class/leds/asus::kbd_backlight"

# $KBBL may a directory or a symlink as of ubuntu 16.04
[ -d $KBBL -o -f $KBBL ] && echo 0 > $KBBL/brightness || echo "$KBBL does not exist!"
```

Make it executable:

```
sudo chmod 0755 /usr/sbin/asuskbbloff
```

Turn on your keyboard backlight and try to switch it off with this command:

```
sudo asuskbbloff
```

When it worked for you, create an upstart-file:

```
sudo gedit /etc/init/asuskbbloff.conf
```

with this content:

```
#
# This task is run on startup to turn of
# keyboard backlight on asus notebooks
# 

description     "turn of keyboard backlight"

start on startup

task
exec /usr/sbin/asuskbbloff
```

Reboot your system for testing.

Comment: I edited the post, did you do it with sudo?

Comment: sudo asuskbbloff says that: /sys/class/leds/asus::kbd_backlight does not exist!

Comment: because it is a directory - I changed the test do `-d`- working now?

Comment: now command asuskbbloff works but it doesn't run on startup

Comment: does the command, when you start it, turn off the backlight?

Comment: @cmks yep, but when i reboot shiny keyboard is back :d

Comment: @Rinzwind it was not working on -f for me but now on -d it works

Comment: try to but the command `/usr/sbin/asuskbbloff` in the file `/etc/rc.local` just before the line `exit 0`

Comment: @cmks so now command asuskbbloff works and now, i guess, all i have to do is to run this command automatically at startup right?

Comment: yes, the upstart file should do that job

Comment: Recap: this works for me on 16.04 with the "-f" option, not the "-d". Files asked for in comment are listed as a "symlink". Using `/etc/rc.local` works during a boot.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't work for me. But if I run

```
echo 3 > $KBBL/brightness
```

and then run

```
echo 0 > $KBBL/brightness
```

it works.