# Turning off ASUS aura in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: keyboard, asus, backlight

I have an [ASUS A15](https://www.asus.com/Laptops/ASUS-TUF-Gaming-A15/) with Ubuntu 20.04 installed. There's a rainbow backlight on the keyboard that might be pleasant if I could control it, but I also think it's eating the battery. I'd like to turn it off.

I tried following the instructions from both answers [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1167084/not-able-to-turn-off-keyboard-backlight-in-ubuntu-18-04-tried-many-solutions), but when I did, I received the following error on the command line:

```
Could not find ROG Aura Core keyboard.
```

So now I'm lost. I've also examined the entire BIOS and found nothing indicating presence of a ROG keyboard. Does anyone have any suggestions for how to do this?

Comment: That's not a typical keyboard backlight.  The downside of "RGB" is a total lack of standardization.  If there's no hardware switch or BIOS settings, you probably have to use the manufacturer's software to configure.   If Asus doesn't provide a Linux version of the software that is required to control the disco lights, you might have to install Windows just for this. Even then, configuration in Windows could be moot if it lacks the capability to store the settings in the firmware